# Laravel 5, Vue 2 - send html form via controller and bind submit action to the component method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to bind action to component method, to the button which is sent via ajax response (json).

So far I have two Vue components - Service and Modal.

**Service:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Services ({{ services.length }})</h1>
        <div class="services-actions">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="openModal">Add Service</button>
        </div>
        <div class="services" v-for="(service, index) in services" :key="service.id">
            <p>{{ service.name }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            services: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAll(){
            axios.get('/admin/services/all', {})
            .then((response) => {
                this.services = response.data
            })
        },
        openModal(){
            axios.get('/admin/services/create', {})
            .then((response) => {
               Event.$emit('modal:show', response.data)
            })

        },
        save(){
            console.log('test');
        }

    },
    mounted(){
        this.getAll()
    }
}
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<template>

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="main-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">


            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted(){

            let mainModal = $('#main-modal')

            Event.$on('modal:show', (html) => {
                mainModal.find('.modal-content').html(html)
                mainModal.modal('show')
            })

            Event.$on('modal:hide', () => {
                mainModal.modal('hide')
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

View file:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>

<form id=service-store action='/admin/service/store'>

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name=name id=name>

</form>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Is it possible bind save changes to the **Service** component **save** method when I click the **Save changes** button?

Comment: Which submit button?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I meant Save changes button from the view file (in the modal-footer)

Comment: Another thing, what is this "View file"? What does it have to do with the others? Is this view file what the `'/admin/services/create'` service returns?

Comment: Yes, this is a html sent via ajax (blade template file) (Laravel controller is sending view file as a json response).